# AngularJS http post to ASP is not getting data

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

When I use the $http post in my AngularJS to a .ASP page which inserts data into a database, I get a successful response with code 200 but the database only gets empty variables.

My AngularJS code:

```
 var email = "test@email.com";
    var firstName = "First Name Test";
    var lastName = "Last Name Test";
    var points = 10;
    var id = "ID TEST";

    $http({
    url: "manageUser.asp",
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        emailPost: email,
        firstNamePost: firstName,
        lastNamePost: lastName,
        pointsPost: points,
        idPost: id
    }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        alert("Success! "+response.status);
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
          alert("Error! "+response.status);
      });
```

My manageUser.asp page:

```
email = request("emailPost")
firstName = request("firstNamePost")
lastName = request("lastNamePost")
points = request("pointsPost")
id = request("idPost")
sql = "INSERT INTO databaseName.tableName (email, firstName, lastName, points, id) VALUES (" &_
   "'" & email & "', " &_ 
   "'" & firstName & "', " &_ 
   "'" & lastName  & "', " &_ 
   "'" & points & "', " &_ 
   "'" & id & "')"
ADODBConn.Execute sql
```

This is the pastebin of the [manageUser.asp](http://pastebin.com/0DWwKJcF) And this is the included [conn.inc](http://pastebin.com/WLgfAX4K) file pastebin

Comment: Could you remove double quotes in data, and try again? For example, `emailPost: ""+email+"",` to `emailPost: email,`

Comment: @Win I tried that, nothing changed. Still getting empty results in my database. A new row is created but the variables remain empty. I edited the post to remove those quotation marks

Comment: Try printing out the value of the variables after you set them to console or log `print email`/`console.log(email)` so you can be sure that `request("emailPost")` is actually returning a value.

Comment: Do you see any JavaScript error? Could you remove `headers: {}`, and please post fiddler session?

Comment: @gh0st I'm not sure how to print to console. I've tried doing Response.write or console.log but 500 Internal Server Error. I don't think it is returning a value though, because if I change it to 'email = "test_email"' that variable shows correctly in the database.

Comment: Ya you might need to use `Request.Params["emailPost"]` or something of the sort. Is `request()` a custom method written by you?

Comment: @Win I removed headers in post, still did not change results. Not sure how I can post this to Fiddler, but I might try to.

Comment: @gh0st I've tried `Request.Params["emailPost"]` and `Request["emailPost"]` but I get a 500 error. request() is not a method I wrote, that's all the code in my asp page except for the include line for connecting to the database, which I know is not the problem. I am using the request() method because it worked for another project where I used javascript to post to asp page

Comment: @Scott do you have a github repo?

Comment: I used to have this similar issue, try to put this `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}`  please

Comment: @gh0st I have a bitbucket repo but I'd honestly rather not share that because there is some information that my boss may not want shared right away. Besides, I'm pretty certain it has something to do with the posted code. In my AngularJS I am using hello.js to authenticate users to facebook. After they login, I get their information and add it to the database. I am also using ngTouch

Comment: @DavidTao I originally posted this question with that exact line you suggested. With or without that, the results do not change.

Comment: "id"s are usually numeric and usually autogenerated by the database after you insert a record. Unless this is an update, which would require a valid "id". Try using a number instead of a random string or leave it out completely.

Comment: @Scott is your `.asp` using C#?

Comment: @Hoyen In this case, the id is a string I will create for the user in the database. It's not use to be unique and not used as a number. Points is an integer however. I have tested them out by declaring the variables in the .asp page and it works correctly. But sending it to AngularJS to .asp is where nothing happens.

Comment: @gh0st I don't believe this is using C#, but not entirely sure what you mean

Comment: @Scott can you pastebin your manageUser.asp page?

Comment: Also, My database is a Microsoft SQL with those fields I have declared... I am planning to use the email as a unique identifier once it works. It doesn't have a unique id for each row at the moment.

Comment: @gh0st This is the pastebin of the [manageUser.asp](http://pastebin.com/0DWwKJcF) And this is the included [conn.inc](http://pastebin.com/WLgfAX4K) file pastebin

Comment: See what happens when you `request("emailPost").ToString()` to all of those. Also I think you should be using `Request["emailPost"].ToString()`.

Comment: @gh0st I tried it both ways, also with and without brackets. With capital R, without. With and without ToString(). Each time I do any of those I get a Internal Server Error 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Turns out AngularJS sends the data as JSON regardless of the headers. So I solved it by adding jQuery then adding $.param around the data.

```
var email = "test@email.com";
    var firstName = "First Name Test";
    var lastName = "Last Name Test";
    var points = 10;
    var id = "ID TEST";

    $http({
    url: "manageUser.asp",
    method: 'POST',
    data: $.param({
        emailPost: email,
        firstNamePost: firstName,
        lastNamePost: lastName,
        pointsPost: points,
        idPost: id
    })
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        alert("Success! "+response.status);
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
          alert("Error! "+response.status);
      });
```